# Does fluffy pony really own and run MoneroDice website?

Tags: monerodice

Reading the faq on monerodice. It says fluffypony owns and runs that website. How can one verify this claim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He responded to many topics regarding MoneroDice from [his Reddit account](https://www.reddit.com/user/fluffyponyza) and he's a moderator of the [monerodice subreddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/monerodice/).

His GitHub account also [confirms he's running the site](https://github.com/Seuntjie900/DiceBot/issues/12).